# Android resizing ImageView inside Layout

Tags: android, resize, android-imageview

I don't know why this is not working correctly. I'm adding an image inside of a layout container. I want the image to be 768x1024 and the container to be 500x500. I am doing this so I can slide around the image for a game, but I cannot get the image to be larger than the container. The image resizes to the size of the container.

```
          containerView = new RelativeLayout(this);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutForContainer = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     layoutForContainer.height = 500;
     layoutForContainer.width = 500;
     layoutForContainer.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
     containerView.setLayoutParams(layoutForContainer);  
     layout.addView(containerView); 

     myImageView = new ImageView(this);
     myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myImage); 
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutForLargeImage = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     layoutForLargeImage.height = 768;
     layoutForLargeImage.width = 1024;
     myImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutForLargeImage); 
     containerView.addView(myImageView);
```

Comment: `ImageView.setScaleType()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Comment: This does not change the size of the ImageView only changes how the image inside the ImageView fits.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
myImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
myImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Comment: It does not change anything, myImageView is still the same size as the container.